# python urlencode multiple same variables

Tags: python, urlencode

I've read the other posts about python(v2) urlencode and didn't find this question.

How can I utilize the urlencode (if that is the right tool to use) if I have multiple variables, but all having the same name? So say the URL is:

http://path.com/a?var=earth&var=wind&var=fire

If I define this:

```
url = 'http://path.com/a?'
query_args = {'var': 'earth',
              'var': 'wind',
              'var': 'fire'}
encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args, doseq=True)
print url + encoded_args
```

It seems urlencode returns only the last 'var' defined:

http://path.com/a?var=fire

How can I get all var's encoded?

Comment: Try printing `query_args`.

Comment: You need to retreat a few paces and study up on dictionaries.  In any computer programming language, you have to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

> Convert a mapping object or ***a sequence of two-element tuples*** to a “percent-encoded” string...

So ... like this:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode([('var', 'earth'), ('var', 'wind')])
'var=earth&var=wind'
```

The "problem" is that the dictionary you are passing to `urlencode` only has one key/value pair:

```
>>> {'var': 'earth',
...  'var': 'wind',
...  'var': 'fire'}
{'var': 'fire'}
```

because a dictionary can only have a particular key in it once.  Allowing urlencode to accept a sequence of 2-element tuples is exactly for this reason (and for the off-chance urls where the *order* of the query parameters matter)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought I read it only accepts lists. It never occurred to me urlencode would accept dictionaries. This makes sense and works like a charm. Thanks!